# Replace fragments in FrameLayout layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have tried every tutorial on the first google page about android fragments, but I can't get anything to work.

So I have one navigation bar activity, `MainActivity`.
Now I'd like to change fragments on a click in the drawer.

In my `content_main` (default fragment in the `MainActivity` activity), I have a framelayout that I wish to put the fragments in. I have the following fragments: `fragment_main`, `fragment_one` and `fragment_two`. And I wish to show these when I click on a button in the nav drawer.

The reason I want to use fragments is so that the nav drawer will stay on top.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is the function I'll use to change fragments:
It's just to test, not finished.

```
public void setFragment() {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction;
    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new LoginFragment());
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Share your code where you are trying to replace fragments.

Comment: Please post your code, what you have tried yet.

Comment: This tutorial is very helpfull! https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it!

Apparently, I had to use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` instead of `android.app.Fragment;`.
This is the code I got it to work with:

```
protected void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    t.commit();
}
```

And to set it (from the nav bar `onNavigationItemSelected()`, you do this:

```
setFragment(new RoosterFragment());
```

I hope this helps others out with the same frustrating problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this? [Click here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/)

This link will Help you, to create `fragment`.
and this is what you want for **navigation drawer**[Click here](https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-sliding-navigation-drawer-example.html)

Comment: The navigation drawer is built in, so I don't need help with that. I also can't get the FragmentTransaction to work. But others are helping me with that too.

Answer (score 1):

### Accroding to your question,

This is **FrameLayout**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_margin"></FrameLayout>
```

---

Now , call displayview method onCreate() of your activity,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //rest of your code here
    displayView(0); // fragment at 0 position
}
```

---

**displayView method**, which have three fragements

```
public void displayView(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                tvTitle.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.signin_tile));
                showFragment(new LoginFragment(), position);
                break;
            case 1:
                tvTitle.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.forgot_password_tile));
                showFragment(new ForgotPasswordFragment(), position);
                break;
            case 2:
                tvTitle.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.change_password_tile));
                showFragment(new ChangePasswordFragment(), position);
                break;

        }
    }
```

---

**showFragment method** called from displayView method,

```
public void showFragment(Fragment fragment, int position) {
        FragmentTransaction mTransactiont = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        mTransactiont.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());
        mTransactiont.commit();
    }
```

Comment: change name of LoginFragment to yourFragment names AS LoginFragment  to FragmentOne

Comment: I removed the error by changing the `import android.app.Fragment` to `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Sorry to bother you with that.

Comment: But yet again when I compile your code, I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nl.broekhin.magizon/nl.broekhin.magizon.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: nl.broekhin.magizon.MainActivity@7f0d233 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener`

Comment: please extend your activity to FragmentActivity where you are using this code.

Comment: Are you using extend to activity or AppCompatActivity ?

Comment: I am using `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {`. Do I change it into `public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {`? It won't let me `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` then.

Comment: no need to change. AppCompatActivity  allways implements FragmentActivity

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,OnFragmentInteractionListener

Comment: It now wants me to import either `RoosterFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener` or `LoginFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener`.

Comment: what is name of your fragment ? use that. import that.

Comment: But I want to be able to show more fragments. LoginFragment, and RoosterFragment, and some more that I will add.

Comment: i will be imported or will ask you to import when you declare it

Comment: If I add this: `RoosterFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener`, it tells me to either declare it abstract, or implement abstract method 'onFragmentInteraction(Uri)' in 'OnFragmentInteractionListner'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. it is my newbie code easier to understand :)

```
FragmentTransaction transaction;

switch (id){
            case R.id.button_fragment_one:
                    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, new FragmentOne());
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                break;
            case R.id.button_fragment_two:
                    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, new FragmentTwo());
                    transaction.commit();
                break;
            default:
                break;
}
```

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nl.broekhin.magizon/nl.broekhin.magizon.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: nl.broekhin.magizon.MainActivity@1092e59 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener` I have been getting this error every time I try to use fragments.

Comment: can you show you fragment activity code? and how you call it?

Comment: @Rachid I have added it.