# the activity does not replace by the fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to call the fragment from activity but the fragment layout doesn't replace the activity , it's like build the fragment on it , so they appear both of them . how can I replace it , it does not work 
Here is the

**activity.java**

```
public class AllTasks extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_tasks);
        final Button add;
        final EditText text;
        final ListView list;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //  public void onClick(View view) {
        ParseObject showlist = new ParseObject("ShowAllTasks");
        showlist.put("TaskNames", showlist);

        showlist.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                Toast.makeText(AllTasks.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ShowAllTasks");
                // query.whereEqualTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> tasklist, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (ParseObject j : tasklist) {
                                array.add(j.getString("TaskNames"));
                            }
                            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(AllTasks.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
                            list.setAdapter(adapter);
                            // Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View view) {
                                       Fragment frag;
                                       FragmentManager fm = AllTasks.this.getFragmentManager();
                                       FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                                       frag = new AddTaskFragment();
                                       //AddTaskFragment llf = new AddTaskFragment();
                                       ft.replace(R.id.alltasks, frag);
                                       ft.addToBackStack(null);
                                       ft.commit();
                                   }
                                   //Intent myIntent = new Intent(AllTasks.this , AddTaskFragment.class);
                                   //startActivity(myIntent);
                               });
    }
    //  });
}
```

Here it's **xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.AllTasks"
android:id="@+id/alltasks">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="YourTasks :"
    android:id="@+id/textViewyourtasks"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="386dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/deletebutton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/deletebutton"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:id="@+id/addbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/deletebutton"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:id="@+id/deletebutton"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewyourtasks"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
```

the **fragment**

```
public class AddTaskFragment extends Fragment {
    public AddTaskFragment() {}

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_task, container, false);

        Button add;
        final EditText tasktext;
        final EditText taskdate;
        final EditText tasknote;
        taskdate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDate);
        tasktext = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTexttaskname);
        tasknote = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextnote);

        add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addbutton);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View view) {
                                       ParseObject showlist = new ParseObject("ShowAllTasks");
                                       showlist.put("TaskNames", tasktext.getText().toString());
                                       showlist.put("Date", taskdate.getText().toString());
                                       showlist.put("Note", tasknote.getText().toString());
                                       showlist.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void done(ParseException e) {
                                               taskdate.setText("");
                                               tasknote.setText("");
                                               tasktext.setText("");
                                               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                               Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AllTasks.class);
                                               getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);

                                           }
                                       });
                                   }
                               }
        );
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

the **fragment.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.AddTaskFragment"
android:id="@+id/fo">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:longClickable="false">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextDate"
        android:hint="Enter task date  "
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextnote"
        android:hint="Enter any note  "
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTexttaskname"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editTextDate" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTexttaskname"
        android:hint="Enter task name here  "
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextDate"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/AddButton"
        android:id="@+id/addbutton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can any one help me to find what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: Fragment can be a part of an activity and not replace the activity. Your understanding is wrong or your explanation is misspell

Comment: try as in answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35334837/2826147

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your aim correctly. 
If you want to show both the current content of the Activity and the Fragment then you should add an another layout in your Activity layout file inside the root RelativeLayout and add your Fragment to that layout from code.

Comment: No , it's already showen on each other , i want when i click the button the activity replaced with the fragment .

Comment: You have to wrap the current content into a fragment, add this fragment to the activity instead of adding the separate Views and replace this fragment to the other one on button click.