# Replace the loaded fragment/page in ViewPager

Tags: android

I have created a `ViewPager` with 10 fragments, in the 3rd fragment i have two buttons called Next and Skip. If i press `Next` button `view pager` should display 4th fragment that is fine, but when i press `Skip` button `view pager` should display the 7th fragment.

Any solution for this is appreciable, Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: use viewPager.setCurrentItem(position)

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/35334837/2826147. it is same as you want just change position as you want.