# How to call a fragment inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I'm working in Fragments that has 2 Fragments in it. take a look at the image below:

The first fragment that shows the list of the inventory is named **fragment_purchase_item_list** and on the right side is the **fragment_purchase_list**

[image]

What I want to do is when I clicked **SCAN** from the toolbar on the right fragment, **fragment_qrscan** will replace **fragment_purchase_item_list**. Like this image below:

[image]

Can someone please see and check why my code is not working? Thanks!

PurchaseListFragment.java

```
<-- start of code snippet -->
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.btn_paypurchasetransaction:
                Fragment chargeFragment = new ChargeFragment();

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.customersales_content, chargeFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
            case R.id.layout_transaction_qrcode:
//                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scan Item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Fragment scanQRCodeFragment = new QRScanFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = fragmentManager1.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.inventory_fragment, scanQRCodeFragment);
                fragmentTransaction1.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction1.commit();

                break;
            case R.id.layout_transaction_new:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "New Transaction", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }
    }

<-- end of code snippet>
```

fragment_sales.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.SalesFragment"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/customersales_content">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/inventory_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.devcash.Fragments.PurchaseItemListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_purchase_item_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3">

    </fragment>

    <View
        style="@style/Divider"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/purchaselist_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.devcash.Fragments.PurchaseListFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_purchase_list">


    </fragment>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `getFragmentManager()` with `getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The app will stop after adding `getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: I think because I have already indicated the name and layout of my fragment container in my `fragment_sales.xml`

Comment: replace your fragment in xmls with a frame layout and then try the fragment replace code

Comment: Yes, but the 1st layout will not automatically show if I do that.

Comment: It will show. Add that fragment in onCreateView() of your parent fragments

Comment: Do you have a link on that reference? I'm not an experienced Android dev (still learning) and I have no clue how to write that code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35334401/replace-fragments-in-framelayout-layout. You can use this link as reference.

Comment: Doesn't help me either :(

Comment: @BeverlyCastillo can you replace with the updated code in your question